# Parallax-style header scrolling performance in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, parallax

I'm developing a parallax-style header/background block in my flutter application, which scrolls upwards at around 1/3 the speed of the foreground content. All parts in the foreground are within the same customScrollView and the background header is in a positioned container at the top of the stack.

[image]

[image]

I'm using a listener on the customscrollview to update a y-offset integer, and then using that integer to update the top position on the element inside my stack.

While this works as expected, the issue I'm facing is a large amount of repainting takes place on scroll, which in the future may impact performance. I'm sure there may be a more efficient way to achieve this - such as placing the entire background in a separate child widget and passing the controller down to it from the parent widget - however I am struggling to find any information on doing so, or if this is the correct approach.

Can someone point me in the right direction for refactoring this in such a way as to disconnect the scrolling background from the foreground, so that the foreground doesn't repaint constantly?

```
class ScrollingWidgetList extends StatefulWidget {
    ScrollingWidgetList();

    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
       return _ScrollingWidgetList();
    }
  }

 class _ScrollingWidgetList extends State<ScrollingWidgetList> {
    ScrollController _controller;
    double _offsetY = 0.0;
    _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _offsetY = _controller.offset;
     });
  }

 @override
   void initState() {
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned(
      top: -(_offsetY / 3),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: new BoxConstraints(
              maxHeight: 300.0,
              minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35),
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topRight,
                end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                colors: [
                  Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                  Colors.blueGrey[900].withOpacity(0.8)
                ],
              )),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35)),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    ),
    CustomScrollView(controller: _controller, slivers: [
      SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 8.0),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                child: Text('Header text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.white)),
              ),
              subtitle: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Text('Subtitle text',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ))
      ])),
      SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return FakeItem(
              executing: false,
              delay: index.isOdd,
              complete: false,
              cancelled: false);
        },
        childCount: 30,
      )),
    ])
  ],
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: do not use `setState` after each scroll - it rebuilds the whole widget - instead use `AnimatedBuilder` for example

Comment: Can you do your scrolling effect with slivers? I don't know how good this tutorial is, but there are a bunch of images that show the different sliver behavior: https://www.raywenderlich.com/19539821-slivers-in-flutter-getting-started

Comment: but actually `CustomMultiChildLayout` is much more handy in your case instead of `Stack` / `AnimatedBuilder` / `Positioned` spaghetti

Comment: @pskink yeah I started looking at AnimatedBuilder and I couldn't quite see a way to handle it in the way that I envisioned, I'll do some reading around customMultiChildLayout today!

Comment: @pskink hey mate, wasn't working over the weekend. I've been playing with your code and the animatedbuilder example is pretty much spot on. CustomMultiChildLayout works really well too, however opted with #1 for simplicity sake. That would likely be good as a separate answer rather than a comment in the thread!

Comment: so we disagree, i think that `CustomMultiChildLayout` is much more simple and logical solution ;-( as it does not have any `ConstrainedBox` / `MediaQuer.of` etc and all the measure / layout stuff is done in one place (`ScrollingWidgetList2Delegate`), moreover it "combines" `Stack / AnimatedBuilder / Positioned` widgets in one widget so that widget spaghetti code is much reduced

Comment: I'm honestly not as familiar with the multichildlayout, but I do agree it's a lot smaller and tidier

Comment: Further to this, I've had more of a play with the `CustomMultiChildLayout` and it does seem to be the better option as you suggested. It also seems to run a lot smoother. I'd probably suggest your code snippet gets put in as an actual answer so I can mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution was added by @pskink in the comments, however they seemed to have removed it. For anyone searching for an elegant solution, this is the basics of what was settled on.

You can see in the below code there is two layouts that are being handled by `CustomMultiChildLayout`. Hopefully this helps anyone searching for a similar solution

```
     class ScrollList extends StatelessWidget {
      final ScrollController _controller = ScrollController();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return CustomMultiChildLayout(
          delegate: ScrollingChildComponentDelegate(_controller),
          children: <Widget>[
            // background element layout
            LayoutId(
              id: 'background',
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // box decoration
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // foreground element layout
            LayoutId(
                id: 'scrollview',
                child: CustomScrollView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    slivers: [
                      SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('TitleText'),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text('SubtitleText'),
                            )),
                      ),
                      SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(itemBuilder,
                            childCount: 100),
                      ),
                    ],
          
                )),
          ],
        );
      }
    }

    // itembuilder for child components
    Widget itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Card(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
          child: ClipPath(
              clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              child: Container(
                // child element content
                )));
    }

    // controller for the animation
    class ScrollingChildComponentDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {

      final ScrollController _controller;
      ScrollingChildComponentDelegate(this._controller) : super(relayout: _controller);

      @override
      void performLayout(Size size) {
        positionChild('background', Offset(0, -_controller.offset / 3));
        layoutChild('background',
            BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: size.width, height: size.height * 0.2));
        positionChild('scrollview', Offset.zero);
        layoutChild('scrollview', BoxConstraints.tight(size));
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRelayout(covariant MultiChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
    }
```